# Move printed notices above page title in woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, message

I am using Woocommerce and I need to move the Woocommerce messages (most importantly ALL messages that are displayed on the single product page) to ABOVE the page title (my theme is using the product title as the page title). I know I can remove one message by using

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'remove_add_to_cart_message' );

function remove_add_to_cart_message() {
return;
}
```

but I need it for all single-product-page messages, and I need them to be readded again above the page title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version it changed in, but the action has changed to `woocommerce_output_all_notices` so it should be...

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
```

Tested on 3.7.0